# Using own SMTP server with GSuite

Tags: smtp, google-workspace

We've been having problems recently with our email ending up in junk and after doing some testing it turns out that (some of) the GSuite IPs have been blacklisted, which explains the partial deliverability.

E-mail is very integral to our business so we'd happily pay to have a dedicated IP but Google doesn't give that option.

Is there a way to force outgoing email to go through a custom SMTP that we'll setup with another provider that can offer dedicated IPs?

Answer (score 2):

Of-course you can use an alternative smtp server.  The only thing to do is ensure any SPF record for your domain includes this.

That said, running your own SMTP server is non-trivial, and you may be better off looking at the quality of your content then blaming googles mail servers - as it is somewhat unlikely that googles mail server IP addresses are the only reason your mail is being classified as spam on a significant scale and its really the recipients job to fix this.

If you are still going to do this  make sure that the static IP provider has forward and reverse IP address matching and th IP is not in a block listed in any RBL's.

Comment: as I mentioned in the OP I already tested that and the email came out with no important flags, only the IP came out on a blacklist. I also mentioned that we would use another managed service that offers dedicated IPs for SMTP, not go out on a limb to build our own server. It would help if you actually explained what's involved in instructing outgoing email in GSuite to go through another SMTP server than their own.